# Ways to grab the data which a browser sends to a server?

Tags: networking, browser

How can I grab the data which the browser sends to a server?

Is there any specific application for it?(windows and linux systems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chrome developer console lists all network transactions under the network tab (you can access by pressing f12). Firefox has an extension called firebug with similar features. I believe that the newest version of IE may have something similiar.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can go at this:

- You could install a browser plugin which allows you to see all the HTTP traffic that is sent. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) has this option ("Net" tab).
- You could use a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture all the raw TCP data.